# R Dataframe issue preventing normality test

Tags: r, dataframe

I've read my .CSV and then converted the file to a data frame using several methods including:

```
df<-read.csv('cdSH2015Fall.csv', dec = ".", na.strings = c("na"), header=TRUE, 
row.names=NULL, stringsAsFactors=F)


df<-as.data.frame(lapply(df, unlist)) # converted .csv to a a data.frame

str(df) # provides the structure of df. 
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ trtGroup            : Factor w/ 68 levels "AANN","AAPN",..: 5 7 14 18 20 23 
27 33 37 48 ...
 $ cd                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PreviousExp         : Factor w/ 2 levels "Empty","Enriched": 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 
1 1 1 ...
 $ treatment           : Factor w/ 2 levels "NN","PN": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ total.Area.DarkBlue.: num  827 1037 663 389 983 ...
 $ numberOfGroups      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ totalGroupArea      : num  15.72 2.26 9.45 11.57 9.73 ...
 $ averageGrpArea      : num  15.72 2.26 9.45 11.57 9.73 ...
 $ proximityToPlants   : num  5.65 16.05 2.58 9.65 4.74 ...
 $ latFeed             : num  2 0.5 0 1 0 0 1 0.5 2 1 ...
 $ latBalloon          : num  6 2 2 NA 0 0.1 3 0.5 1 0.7 ...
 $ countChases         : int  5 8 16 4 16 21 18 11 14 28 ...
 $ chases              : int  95 87 67 923 636 96 1210 571 775 816 ...
 $ grpDiameter         : num  16.8 23.3 19.5 11.2 29.9 ...
 $ grpActiv            : num  4908 5164 4197 5263 5377 ...
 $ NND                 : num  0 11.88 8.98 3.6 9.8 ...
```

I then run my model two ways:

First option.

```
 fit = t.test(df$proximityToPlants[which (df$cd==1 & 
    df$treatment == 'PN')], df$proximityToPlants[which 
    (df$cd==0 & df$treatment == 'PN')]
    )
```

Second option trying to ensure I have a proper data frame.

- Subset the data and then create a matrix.

  ```
   cdProximityToPlantsPN<-cdSH2015Fall$proximityToPlants[which (cdSH2015Fall$cd==1 & cdSH2015Fall$treatment == 'PN')]
  H2ProximityToPlantsPN<-cdSH2015Fall$proximityToPlants[which (cdSH2015Fall$cd==0 & cdSH2015Fall$treatment == 'PN')]

  cdProximityToPlantsNN<-cdSH2015Fall$proximityToPlants[which (cdSH2015Fall$cd==1 & cdSH2015Fall$treatment == 'NN')]
  H2ProximityToPlantsNN<-cdSH2015Fall$proximityToPlants[which (cdSH2015Fall$cd==0 & cdSH2015Fall$treatment == 'NN')]
  ```
- Creating a matrix

  ```
  df<- 
    cbind(cdProximityToPlantsPN,H2ProximityToPlantsPN,cdProximityToPlantsNN, 
  H2ProximityToPlantsNN)
  mat <- sapply(df,unlist)
  fit=t.test(mat[,1],mat[,2], paired = F, var.equal = T)
  ```

Yet, I still get errors when assessing outliers using the following:

```
outlierTest(fit) # Bonferonni p-value for most extreme obs
Error in UseMethod("outlierTest") : 
  no applicable method for 'outlierTest' applied to an object of class 
 "htest"
qqPlot(fit, main="QQ Plot") #qq plot for studentized resid 
Error in order(x[good]) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
leveragePlots(fit) # leverage plots
Error in formula.default(model) : invalid formula
```

I know the issue must be with my data structure. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: `?car::outlierTest` says it takes an lm or glm object. `t.test` does not produce either of these.

Comment: apart form what @blindjesse  has pointed out, read.csv would have produced a dataframe right away, why was it `unlist`ed?

Comment: @blindjesse, yes, you're right about the car::outlierTest. I don't understand why qqPlot is not working?

Comment: @R.S. yes, I thought read.csv would produce a data.frame. I don't know why qqPlot is stating that I have a 'list'. Because I got the 'list' error when running qqPlot, I thought read.csv was not creating a proper 'data.frame'.

Comment: That is because you are  passing the `t.test` output to `qqplot` and it is  probably unclassing it and getting a list.  You probably wanted to qqplot some particular columns in your data-frame, was it?

Comment: BTW , you don't need those `which`. The booleans returned by the conditions are sufficient to subset the dataframe.